# Do I still need to use boost for algorithm::join?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, c++14

Very easy question but I've got so used to finding boost functionality as part of STL in C++11 that I was surprised when I couldn't see a `join` function.

Just to double check - it's definitely *not* present in C++11? Is it part of any newer versions of the C++ standard?

Comment: There's no `std::join` yet. However, a proposal has been made http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html

Comment: Yes. <padding/> <padding/> <padding/> <padding/>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `std::join` in C++11 or C++14 so you will still have to use the boost version.  There is an open proposal for it [N3954](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html)

Accorging to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/sd-1.htm The papper has been mailed out and is in the "Library Evolution" sub group.